# SocketRocket crashes after connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, socket.io

So i want to develop a basic chat application using socket.io. I'm using [this](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) framework which is essentially just a wrapper over SocketRocket.

Now i made a connectToHost:onPort and i receive a 200 in didReceiveResponse. The connectionDidFinishLoading also is called. It finally prints Opening URL_NAME in the openSocket method before i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this method:

```
[self _performDelegateBlock:^{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webSocketDidOpen:)]) {  // <- EXC_BAD_ACESSS error here
        [self.delegate webSocketDidOpen:self];
    };
}];
```

Any idea what it could be? From my understanding, the framework i'm using should implement this delegate method of Socket Rocket.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the error and it was rather silly. I should have created a class variable of the SocketIO instance. Thats why the life cycle was over and the delagate was nil.
Ah well!

Comment: Exactly the same problem - gross race condition worsened it. Thanks for reporting and answering.